# MS SQL Server Analysis Server Powershell administrator entitlement

Tags: sql-server, powershell

I am trying to programmatically add an administrator to the MS SQL Server Analysis Server Server Administrators via PowerShell. I can't seem to find a cmdlet or a reasonable method to do this after installation.

This would be the equivalent of launching studio, Right/Click Analysis Server, and choosing the Security Page, and adding a 'server administrator' through the object chooser.

Comment: I have no experience with SSAS, but leveraging my knowledge with the core engine and SMO, I think using [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.analysisservices.server.roles?view=analysisservices-dotnet) to return a collection of roles from the server, choose the role you want from it, and then add a member to that role.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In sqlserver powershell there is a cmdlet Invoke-ASCmd

this can run a script.